# sudo modprobe -r xpad fix?

Tags: gamepad, xbox-360

Is there a fix for Ubuntu 18.04 not recognizing xbox controllers without running the `sudo modprobe -r xpad` and `sudo modprobe xpad` EVERY time I restart?  I know you used to be able to add xboxdrv as a service, but that's not working anymore... Any ideas?

Comment: "Is there a fix for Ubuntu 18.04 not recognizing xbox controllers without running the sudo modprobe -r xpad and sudo modprobe xpad EVERY time I restart?"  make a service. "I know you used to be able to add xboxdrv as a service, but that's not working anymore" why not? https://gist.github.com/akatch/cdb707856d467bd7cacd  Your are trying to fix the wrong problem. Fix the "but that's not working anymore"

Comment: I have it working on 19.04. so please explain what is not working for you. do you get any errors when you run the service? Mind that the modprobe remove and adding of xpad might be the issue too: that should not be needed too. check for errors in /var/log related to this.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/ubuntu-xboxdrv
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-xboxdrv
```

The service will start immediately after installation, but you can always

```
sudo service xboxdrv restart
```

or use typical `systemctl` commands.